# Elasticsearch TermsFacet giving wrong count

Tags: elasticsearch

I had problem with Elasticsearch Term Facet

i put data as follows :

```
curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:9200/articles'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "One",   "tags" : "foo","datetime":"2005-12-23 23:10:52"}'


curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "Two",   "tags" : "bar","datetime":"2005-12-23 23:10:53"}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "Three", "tags" : "baz","datetime":"2005-12-23 23:10:54"}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "four", "tags" : "baz","datetime":"2005-12-23 23:10:55"}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "five", "tags" : "foo","datetime":"2005-12-23 23:10:56"}'
```

so whenever i query for terms facet it gives correct result following is my Elasticsearch query :

```
curl  'http://localhost:9200/articles/article/_search?pretty=true' -d '{

   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
   },
    "facets" : { "myfacet" : { "terms" : {"field" : "tags"}}
    }
}'
```

But, when i added filter to Facet it won't show any facet count following is query :

```
curl  'http://localhost:9200/articles/article/_search?pretty=true' -d '{

   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
   },
   "facets" : {
        "myfacet" : { "terms" : {"field" : "tags"},
             "filter" : { "range" :{
 "datetime" : {"from" : "2005-12-23   3:10:52","to" : "2005-12-23 23:10:56" }

        }
            }
    }
    }
}'
```

I get result as follows

```
facets" : {
    "myfacet" : {
      "_type" : "filter",
      "count" : 0
    }
  }
```

so, anyone know's  why it is giving such count.

Comment: Hi uttamp, did you get a chance to try my answer out?

Answer (score 1):

The dates are in an invalid format, have a look at the supported date time formats that elasticsearch supports (too long, don't read, any date that is supported by jodatime is supported by elasticsearch).

```
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format.html
```

With that being said, you just have to modify your dates in your insert statements and put them in a valid date format, like `2005-12-23T23:10:55Z`.  Then just change your query to the proper time range in that time format, and that should give you the result.

Also be careful when writing these queries, as I noticed the date you used in your from clause is not valid.

Here are the modified curl scripts:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "One",   "tags" : "foo","datetime":"2005-12-23T23:10:52Z"}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "Two",   "tags" : "bar","datetime":"2005-12-23T23:10:53Z"}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "Three", "tags" : "baz","datetime":"2005-12-23T23:10:54Z"}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "four", "tags" : "baz","datetime":"2005-12-23T23:10:55Z"}'

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/article" -d '{"title" : "five", "tags" : "foo","datetime":"2005-12-23T23:10:56Z"}'
```

and the modified search:

```
 curl  'http://localhost:9200/articles/article/_search?pretty=true' -d '{

   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "facets" : {
     "myfacet" : { 
         "terms" : {"field" : "tags"},
         "filter" : { "range" :{
                         "datetime" : {
                             "from" : "2005-12-23T23:10:52Z",
                              "to" : "2005-12-23T23:10:54Z" 
                          }   
                       }
                    }
                  }
             }
}'
```

Hope this helps,
Matt